# Cljs re-frame is not showing element as expected

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

I'm experimenting with Cljs re-frame, in which I'm trying to show a cell in UI with the below function,

```
(defn cell
      [{:keys [id value on-change]}]
      [(r/adapt-react-class Box) {:key              id
                                  :type             :number
                                  :ml               2
                                  :content-editable (nil? value)
                                  :on-change        on-change
                                  :border           "2px solid #10AF34"
                                  :width            "30px"
                                  :height           "30px"
                                  :align            "center"}
       value])
```

When I try to call the method directly from a method that is being invoked for rendering, it **works**,

```
(defn app
      []
      (cell {:id        "1-1"
             :value     nil
             :on-change #(js/alert "in cell 1 1")}))
```

Whereas, when I try to wrap it in another method and call, it is **not working**

```
(defn grid
      [data]
      (cell {:id        "1-1"
             :value     1
             :on-change #(js/alert "in cell 1 1")}))

(defn app
      []
      (grid (generate-data)))
```

If someone wants to try it out, the `grid/cell` is available [here](https://github.com/kannangce/sudoku/blob/main/src/main/app/views/elem.cljs) and the app/rendering function is available [here](https://github.com/kannangce/sudoku/blob/main/src/main/app/core.cljs).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might stem from using  `[(r/adapt-react-class Box) …]` - I‘m not sure it’s problematic, but I‘d either `def` the result of `adapt-react-class` and reuse it, or use the `[:> Box …]` syntax.